# How to stack three relations

Tags: stacking-symbols

Is it possible to stack three relations or symbols ontop of one another? Specifically I would like to stack three symbols, `R`, `\rightleftarrows` and `L` in order to define a pair of adjoint functors $R:C\to D$ and $C\gets D:L$.

Also, is there a `\rightleftarrow` with long arrows? **EDIT** I actually meant to ask wether there is a version of `\rightleftarrows` with long arrows.

I'm not a regular user, so I don't know how to format my question adequately, could someone convert what's inside the dollar so that it appears as latex please?

Comment: For the second question, you have `\longleftrightarrow`. Can you please elaborate on how should the symbols be stacked? Do you have an image of the desired result?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for the command. I would like to have the R$ sit ontop of the leftrightarrow and the L to be below the longrightarrow. Similarly to when one writes `\stackrel{def}{=}` where the def sits atop the equality, I want the `R` to be where the `def` is in my example, and the `L` should be at the same place but below the equality sign.

Comment: `mathtools` provides `\xleftrightarrow[under]{over}`. May be that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
x \mathrel{\substack{R\\\rightleftarrows\\ L}} y
\]

\[
x \mathrel{\substack{R\\\longleftrightarrow\\L}} y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit:

Some hack wrote in a hurry to make long version of `\rightleftarrows`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand{\myrightleftarrows}{\mathrel{\substack{\longrightarrow \\[-.6ex] \longleftarrow}}}

\begin{document}

\[
x \mathrel{\substack{R\\\myrightleftarrows\\L}}  y
\]
%
\[
x \mathrel{\substack{R\\\rightleftarrows\\ L}} y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope this will get you started `:-)`

Comment: Do you know if I can get a long version of the `\rightleftarrows` somehow?

Comment: Are you writing the code yourself? I'm currently using the code for a blogpost edited with wordpress, will I be able to use it in this environment? I'll definitely use it further down the line on a proper Latex compiler, just so you know your efforts will not be wasted :)

Comment: That is fantastic :D thank you very much Harish Kumar!

Answer (score 6):

The [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package offers you `\xleftrightarrow[<above>]{<below>}`; for the second question, standard LaTeX has `\longleftrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\longleftrightarrow\qquad\xleftrightarrow[L\,]{R\,}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I tried using your formula but it didn't work for some reason, maybe it's because I'm using wordpress to write latex.