# LaTeX problem: The \rightleftarrows symbol is too short

Tags: arrows

The `\rightleftarrows` symbol is too short horizontally for my liking. My search engine finds no helpful results for "latex longrightleftarrows". Is there some way to extend the symbol horizontally?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{gensymb}
 ...
\begin{document}
\ce{\rightleftarrows}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91524/32888

Comment: Thanks, Adam. Harish's edit at that link is the output closest to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 10):

If you are happy with `harpoons`, you can use `xleftrightharpoons` from `mathtools`

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\ce{A\rightleftarrows B}

\ce{A\xleftrightharpoons{\rule{2cm}{0pt}} B}

\ce{A\xleftrightharpoons{\hphantom{\hspace*{1cm}}} B}


\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\ce{A\rightleftarrows B}

\ce{A\xleftrightharpoons{\text{my reaction}} B}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variant:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\newcommand{\myrightleftarrows}[1]{\mathrel{\substack{\xrightarrow{#1} \\[-.9ex] \xleftarrow{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\ce{A\rightleftarrows B}

\ce{A\myrightleftarrows{\rule{2cm}{0cm}} B}    %%% change 2cm as you wish
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind. Thank you, Harish.

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to use [`chemfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) you can easily control the arrow attributes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{gensymb}
 \usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\ce{A\rightleftarrows B}

\schemestart
A\arrow{<=>}B 
\schemestop

\setarrowdefault{0,0.7,red,thick}
\schemestart
A\arrow{<=>}B 
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was really hoping for two arrows. Nevertheless, formatting arrows through chemfig is a revelation to me, so thanks for that. I think I'll go with Harish's "hack" linked to by Adam above.