# How to use \leftrightarrows

Tags: arrows

Can anybody tell me how to use`\leftrightarrows`?

Besides what should I do if I insert text above and below it? Thanks.

Comment: @Christoph this is not a duplicate of the linked question; `\leftrightarrows` produces *two* arrows, one on top of each other and pointing in opposite directions. The question/answer you linked to only deals with one arrow having two arrow tips.

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in the [extensible arrows](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DnmMz.png) provided by [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) rather than trying to write above/below `\leftrightarrows` as-is. A possibility, yes?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You are right, I missed the ending 's' :)

Comment: [How do I write above a left-right arrow?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96549/how-do-i-write-above-a-left-right-arrow) is **not** a duplicate. `\leftrightarrows` has *two* lines with one arrow each.

Comment: Related: [LaTeX problem: The \rightleftarrows symbol is too short](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170042/16967)

Answer (score 8):

If the text you want to place above and below is short then the following is one way to use them:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackrel,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\( V \stackrel[\beta]{\alpha}{\leftrightarrows} W \)

\end{document}
```

Longer (`\longleftrightarrows`) and extensible (`\xleftrightarrows`) versions of these arrows can be made with a little effort:

[image: Second sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackrel,amssymb,amsmath}

\newcommand{\leftrarrows}{\mathrel{\raise.75ex\hbox{\oalign{%
  $\scriptstyle\leftarrow$\cr
  \vrule width0pt height.5ex$\hfil\scriptstyle\relbar$\cr}}}}
\newcommand{\lrightarrows}{\mathrel{\raise.75ex\hbox{\oalign{%
  $\scriptstyle\relbar$\hfil\cr
  $\scriptstyle\vrule width0pt height.5ex\smash\rightarrow$\cr}}}}
\newcommand{\Rrelbar}{\mathrel{\raise.75ex\hbox{\oalign{%
  $\scriptstyle\relbar$\cr
  \vrule width0pt height.5ex$\scriptstyle\relbar$}}}}
\newcommand{\longleftrightarrows}{\leftrarrows\joinrel\Rrelbar\joinrel\lrightarrows}

\makeatletter
\def\leftrightarrowsfill@{\arrowfill@\leftrarrows\Rrelbar\lrightarrows}
\newcommand{\xleftrightarrows}[2][]{\ext@arrow 3399\leftrightarrowsfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\( U \stackrel[\beta]{\alpha} \leftrightarrows V
\xleftrightarrows[\text{description under}]{\text{long text}} W
\stackrel[\beta]{\alpha}\longleftrightarrows X \)

\end{document}
```

The technique is to define three parts `\leftrarrows`, `\Rrelbar` and `\lrightarrows` for the left, middle and right parts of the double arrow.  For `\longleftrightarrows` we just joint these three parts together with `\joinrel`; for `\xleftrightarrows` we repeat the `\Rrelbar` as many times as needed to get the required width, using low-level techniques provided by the `amsmath` package.

To do the same for "rightleft" arrows you can use

[image: Rightleft sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackrel,amssymb,amsmath}

\newcommand{\rleftarrows}{\mathrel{\raise.75ex\hbox{\oalign{%
  $\hfil\scriptstyle\relbar$\cr
  \vrule width0pt height.5ex$\scriptstyle\smash\leftarrow$\cr}}}}
\newcommand{\rightlarrows}{\mathrel{\raise.75ex\hbox{\oalign{%
  $\scriptstyle\rightarrow$\hfil\cr
  $\scriptstyle\vrule width0pt height.5ex\relbar$\cr}}}}
\newcommand{\Rrelbar}{\mathrel{\raise.75ex\hbox{\oalign{%
  $\scriptstyle\relbar$\cr
  \vrule width0pt height.5ex$\scriptstyle\relbar$}}}}
\newcommand{\longrightleftarrows}{\rleftarrows\joinrel\Rrelbar\joinrel\rightlarrows}

\makeatletter
\def\rightleftarrowsfill@{\arrowfill@\rleftarrows\Rrelbar\rightlarrows}
\newcommand{\xrightleftarrows}[2][]{\ext@arrow 3399\rightleftarrowsfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\( U \stackrel[\beta]{\alpha} \rightleftarrows V
\xrightleftarrows[\text{description under}]{\text{long text}} W
\stackrel[\beta]{\alpha}\longrightleftarrows X \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! What if the text is long above and below the arrows?

Comment: @MalJA I have now updated my answer to include such arrows.

Comment: Can you please tell me which bit of the \newcommand related to the longarrows in the middle

Comment: @MalJA I have added some more explanation.  For `\xleftrightarrows` you need all the commands I define except `\longleftrightarrows`

Comment: How would one adapt the code for `\rightleftarrows` instead of `\leftrightarrows`?

Comment: @ElíasGuisado Code added.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, how can this be edited for single \longrightarrow? The arrow pair between W and X in the second picture are just perfect! Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: @Tetiana The standard version should be `W \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} X`.