# How do I create this symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, arrows

I looked it up on detexify but apparently it is not an inbuilt symbol[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stack three relations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91521/how-to-stack-three-relations)

Comment: Maybe a bit more closely your specific question (only 2 symbols): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/typeset-an-with-an-above

Comment: Thus: Use the symbols for the Delta (`\Delta`) and the arrow (`\rightarrow`) and tack them on top of each other using the technique in the linked questions.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Great question. I especially appreciate showing that you’d done your due diligence looking for an answer. I’m voting to close because it was answered in the comments.

Answer (score 7):

I think the easiest way is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $X \overset{\triangle}{\longrightarrow} Y$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ X\xrightarrow{\enspace\smash{\raisebox{-0.2\height}{$\scriptstyle\triangle$}}\enspace}Y \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]